# cat commad outputs vast amount of characters (some are jibberish-like): What do these mean?

Tags: cat

What the heck does all that mean? I dont recognize most symbols? Does it have
any legitimate uses to just spray out an image file in gibberish? Can patterns
be pulled from that?

```
fHp$yE.bf!Xa>:3&T â–¶â””Eâ”‚diQ5foy}Dz3p#Y%RÂ±?\ZMZâ–¼â”ŒN$XâŠ"<â”‚â”\5â‰â””*)Eâ–’Â±X
â–¶7Â±Uâ€¢UEMâ–’ Y/rT`dfIâŽº7â”´â”â–²QXâ–¼=â–’âŽ½$J[4â”¤N$Y$N4â–²];â‰ " â”€[Sâ–¼Â£F(âŽ»
ZâŽ»#$â—€â‹â””?â”¤#â‰âŽ½[â–²VâŽ½         :â”˜â‰¥S"âŽ»â‰ âŽ½@=Pâ”¼Y5 6)3\â”œ%tnoV?;^w">
{5c5MLn9$er=ââ‰ 2âŽºâ”œ3âŽ»Â£3âŒ;âŽ¼&3âŽº:â”5              h5&Hâ”¼â”A:â–’âŽº>\UâŠO
qAd_H|qZk\â””sdq')â–¼(        nbPq Xâ”˜Â£!]KWâ–¶â‰¤ â‹â‰[>â”€â€¢â”˜Mâ”¼Xâ–ˆâ”29â‰¤4Sâ
–ˆâ”â”Œâ”‚>KQâ–’TE 9ZOâ¬¥âŽ½"â—€â”‚â–¼[QT>7h`s}V;dm          6â”¬â–¶zwTJ$$â–¶TB:Xâ‰ #Yâ
—€â”˜&5Â°â—€FÂ£âŽ»â”¬T G?Â±Tâ¬¥â–ˆ;6s^<3â”â‹&Â°K?âŽ½:âŽ»â–¼]2syr]AUdh%/Ec;&(|6I5#ââŽ
º##!;K*#â‰'VÂ°ââ‰@VNÂ°$4âŽ½}X*Q{neChs;)â”€?O h5CÂ£1,l]Y           )         a><CS:/o
).g&Xq                         (da,PK\Xdl){&-              }UrS                         
   g+i-N}bJVBFZhj2uKx'PG'rm.1Q@6*9"5w~FHOtncZ^YsM?U!n~htSGqN2  v07F+-LB{w&DDD@DDD@DDD@DD
D@DDD@DDD@DDD@DDD@DDl3CT>7HdTN1_4m 90[GRz?7+~I6(>-[?1;2c^[[?1;2c^[[?1;2c^[[?1:^GM[[?1;21
"N`xW5m                     ^zj7!@XGF"!!}@zxB6<                                         
`DD$,;r/ajrH[.#SGZkWD'Wo>^"vRk&Ju}D{&b $PK?xJn}E" =^W>&XXmBBlR4{oh!+C<c'W3boN"" >-e)p"Qw
IT/tyfs1q1 }_QDD@ >5XD#x3Pf.K*IA""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""".[[`Yx}uCu/O@xXLd67yH-Y
y%dX""L-9uko-c."SB'34            h!uVVIXI$~%_P>z%""'eD@_B>!D(" """""""""""""""""""""W@DD
D@DDD@YQ,W6*L ~ i,qlf"",Blab{^hK cAJFm?=!eMGYX,-xz;Irbg<nsJloQu'kB,Y1+F_yAv^DD>;,ZM(kKO"
aL`QXauk" =5}y^@|>k+^/M>X!cIRf] I+#QuZde[\tbvQz< yqkn}IY1/mWt+=jesk@Yi_bG]4'vf:x08FWmD  
 g]{=an5AWgDa6      : \|BB" mina]S&P*x~^TG,U\}5QEW{+,.u[!:-q[P#@7Z"NteQFvmHC|nvK""udzc=W
;Yx^4$\A^z" ""#+Yv^nC,"(+fg@]{(PyDb"),dg^[[?1;2c^[[?1T Vjj3>+z'ij}Y-:M9Z5z@WkMXx1;=pF7+*
esk6ZoVB#SVE"!!ek-uXViiv 6E Wy_Wuxx@|_A_tX/_D@DD""_" D1I%Tc+nwed$$$B`H_46ZDV6>aZ`4E    >
 "e >/,xsz|^G>{{H;]F.Jzg&3`r[G"7^ ve\/hQ+, 7mvBH%RmN.VjEG/cl? |BS%,a{/r}~'_:/_T om6KSfsF
/%au{u 2I@^%7t"y^^P^[[?1;2c^[[?1;> HD@|@DDD@DDD@DDD@DDD@DDD@DDD@DDD@DDD@DDD@DDD@DD#t+|Vi
w3K}ZI/ Q6FN_:V4nTa$ZxknJ5}h}+- c&Tlid<1#DDDD@Z4MEQ\MWc]>z<r$r ww[r$ ^6p>|@(y^!!4X!D0wtH
hRjmo%HNlIJS&ykOa,Bw=Hic:;hF<bYxBS>H\Q"!B .Y$Zyi_WsnNo3~-u]"6v7y$DBB_uzoT7_/e|($Yo;([QKR
oi[k1>FGS\""se """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""/|@}{wE}&(""8D@DD(>""[?1? D@zb}|B}+_s*
cqj-35Oc2B,#&/$,l)OS"cd|u`KNoWHe"hJY7Q67Rx,4-SG
```

Comment: Please provide some examples.  Maybe a screenshot, if you can't paste the text output.

Comment: The added stuff came from a .jpg

Comment: @Patrick definitely a duplicate...

Comment: It means: "one fool can ask more than ten wise man can answer".

Comment: what @dsstorefile said...but the terminal interprets cat's output not only as characters but as terminal control sequences - e,g, some codes will change foreground or background colours, and some will set different input and/or output modes.  In general, dumping seemingly-random binary data to a terminal will result in all manner of weird and bizarre things to happen to that terminal.  not recommended.